# Is an expectation over two variables equivalent to the expectation over the first of the expectation over the second?

Tags: expected-value

My question is in regards to this surrogate advantage function used in the Trust Region Policy Optimization (TRPO) reinforcement learning algorithm.
$${L}(\theta_k, \theta) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{s,a \sim \pi_{\theta_k}}{ \frac{\pi_{\theta}(a|s)}{\pi_{\theta_k}(a|s)} A^{\pi_{\theta_k}}(s,a) }$$
Is this expectation over all (state, action) pairs in the policy ${\pi_{\theta_k}}$ of $\frac{\pi_{\theta}(a|s)}{\pi_{\theta_k}(a|s)} A^{\pi_{\theta_k}}(s,a)$ equivalent to: $$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{s \sim \pi_{\theta_k}}[\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{a \sim \pi_{\theta_k}}{ \frac{\pi_{\theta}(a|s)}{\pi_{\theta_k}(a|s)} A^{\pi_{\theta_k}}(s,a) }]$$
Would this be equivalent to a double integral, or is there something different between expecting over ${s,a}$ pairs and expecting over them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) says that if you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, potentially with some dependency between them, then the overall expectation of $X$ can be found by first taking the expectation conditional on $Y$ then taking the expectation over $Y$. In other words,

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}_Y \left[ \mathbb{E}_X[X|Y] \right]$$

Comment: So my double expectation formulation isn't quite right then, I would need to condition the inner expectation on s, right?

Comment: That's right. In terms of integrals, that may also affect the bounds of integration.